# Not editable checkboxes on True value in Django admin

Tags: python, django, forms, checkbox

models

```
class Company(BaseModel): 
    rag_soc = models.CharField(_("Ragione Sociale"), max_length=255, blank=False, null=False)
    sure = models.BooleanField(_("Continua Modifiche"), default= False)
    p_iva = models.CharField(_("Partita IVA/Codice Fiscale"), max_length=16, blank=True, null=True, unique = True)
    ref_name_1 = models.CharField(_('Nome Referente'), max_length=70, blank=False, null=False)
    ref_name_2 = models.CharField(_('Nome Referente'), max_length=70, blank=True, null=True)
    compentecy = models.CharField(_("Competenza"), max_length=255, choices=COMPETENCY, blank=False)
    commodity_sector = models.CharField(_("Settore Merceologico"), max_length=255, choices=ATECO, blank=True, null=True)
    employees = models.IntegerField(_('Numero Dipendenti'), max_length=4, blank=True, default = 0 )

class OutCome(BaseModel):
    outcome = models.CharField(_("Esito"), max_length=25, choices=OUTCOME, blank=False, null=True)
    out_date = models.DateTimeField(_("In Data"), blank=True, null=True)
    return_date = models.BooleanField(_('Richiamata'), default=False,)
    notes = models.TextField(_("Note"), max_length=512, blank=True, null=True)
    seller = models.BooleanField(_('Richiesta Venditore'), default=False, blank = True)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company, verbose_name=_('Azienda'), related_name='company_set')
```

admin

```
class CompanyParent(admin.ModelAdmin):
    change_form_template = 'admins/change_form_company.html'

    list_display = ('rag_soc', 'city', 'return_user', 'lastMod')
    search_fields = ('rag_soc', 'p_iva', 'city', 'seller__name', 'seller__surname')
    list_filter = ('compentecy', 'seller', 'user', 'created', 'conf_company', 'prov_conf_company')

    form = CompanyForm
    list_per_page = 55
    inlines = [OutComeOffersList, OutComeList, OutComeAdd]

class OutComeList(PaginationInline):
    order_by = ('-created',)
    form = OutcomeForm
    model = OutCome
    can_delete = False
    extra = 1
    verbose_name = 'Contatto Precedente'
    verbose_name_plural = 'Contatti Precedenti'
    readonly_fields = ['outcome', 'out_date', 'created', 'seller', 'notes',]
```

In every instance inline of OutCome, i need to display a green checkmark if the instance is True, an empty checkbox if it's False.
How can i do it? Thanks

Comment: if the instance is True, I am confused about it, could you express it more clearly?

Comment: if the return_date field of every outcome instance is True, i want to display a checkmark insted of a checked checkbox, if return_date is False, i display an empty checkbox. I need to do this because if the user checkes the checkbox, later he can no more edit this field (if the user checks True this checkbox and save it, than it would'n be editable)

Answer (score 0):

you can display different content according to the return_date field

models.py

```
class OutCome(BaseModel):
    ...
    return_date = models.BooleanField(_('Richiamata'), default=False,)
    ...
    def return_date_ctrl(self):
        if self.return_date: # if is true
            return u'<img src="/media/checkmark.png" />'
        else:
            # you can use js & ajax to control this
            return u'<input type="checkbox" id="id_out_date" name="out_date" />'
    return_date_ctrl.short_description = 'return date'
    return_date_ctrl.allow_tags = True
```

admin.py

```
class OutComeList(PaginationInline):
    ...
    # add return_date_ctrl to readonly_fields
    readonly_fields = ['return_date_ctrl', ...]
```

Hoped I provide the route may help you!